# Rudimentary question about differential equations.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

One thing I have never understood about differential equations is how we can just consider the homogenous case in order to solve the equation.

for example for any second-order linear ODE:
$$ \alpha\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \beta\frac{dy}{dx} + \gamma y = P(x) $$

why do we solve this for $P(x) = 0$ as its own seperate solutions, in other words why is the paticular integral not the only solution?

Comment: Nobody does "just consider the homogeneous case". Instead, one can use the solution of the homogeneous equation to obtain the solution of the inhomogeneous equation (at least, those who studied the theory thoroughly can do that). Unfortunately, it works only for linear differential equations.

Comment: because for a LINEAR differential equation, the sum of a homogeneous and a particular solution would solve the equation ( the RHS would be $0 + P(x)$)

Answer (score 1):

Don’t forget that when we speak of a solution, we **also speak of the initial conditions** $y(x_0)=y_0$ and $y^\prime(x_0)=y_1$.

The homogeneous equation has a unique solution **given the initial conditions**. This can be used by addition  to find a solution of the equation with the RHS equal to $P$ and the initial conditions.

This works as a sum of solutions of a linear equation is also a solution of the equation.